# *Redundant* - custom-javascript-variable to select second class in an element

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have just realised why this isn't working for me. The data isn't available at the time of the trigger event. I need to wait for an AJAX call to return before filling the variable. Classic case of PEBKAC.

I have a div with two classes, one of which is class1 the other can be either class2 or class3. 
I need the function to return just the second class from the div. 
At the moment the code creates an array of classes in the console but isn't doing anything in GTM.
In GTM it is supposed to fill a custom JavaScript variable with the contents of classes[1] which would be either class2 or class3

```
function() {
  var classes = $('.class1').attr('class').split(' ');
  return classes[1];
}
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: what is it supposed to do in GTM?

Comment: Can you provide more context (code) for the question?

Comment: In GTM it is supposed to fill a custom JavaScript variable with the contents of classes[1] which would be either class2 or class3

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are calling your anonymous function after the document is ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var secondClass = myFunc();
  $('#output').text(secondClass)
  
});

var myFunc = function(){
  var classArray = $('.class1').attr("class").split(' ');
  return classArray[1];
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```